# Couchbase Sync Gateway User Password Reset

Tags: couchbase-sync-gateway

I have a Windows Server 2012 running Couchbase Server and Sync Gateway. I am able to access the Sync Gateway locally, but am unsure how to reset a user account password. I have been able to add a new user via the Admin API on port 4985.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change a user account password send PUT to the user account.

```
$ curl -iX PUT http://localhost:4985/default/_user/myuser --data
'{"email":"myuser@gmail.com", "name":"myuser", "password":"NEW_password",
"admin_channels":["myuser", "public", "NEW_channel"]}'
```

[Couchbase Fourms - Update user info with Admin REST API](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/update-user-info-with-admin-rest-api/2346/2)

Comment: I found I had to do it this way - adding to the config file did not work for some reason.